# Retrieving Multiple Values from History table in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a table T1

```
Current-------History
---5-------------6--
---6-------------4--
---2-------------3--
```

Let's say I wish to retrieve them in sequence by most recent, it would be 5-> 6 ->4. How can I derive the final history is 4 given a number of 5 with the assumption that the digit will only have 2 past history.

This is my current code:

```
Select t1.current, t1.history,select (t1.history where t1.current in (t1.history) )

From t1
```

Comment: what are you using mssql or mysql?

Comment: Microsoft Sql server

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider `rderby`

... take your query, add this `orderby` and switch with the switch case too add more

```
WHERE
   t1.current IN (t1.history, t2.history , 'a') ...
ORDER BY
   CASE t1.current
      WHEN 't1.history' THEN 1
      WHEN 't2.history' THEN 2
      --     WHEN 'a' THEN 3
      ELSE 5 --needed only is no IN clause above. eg when = 't2.history'
   END, id
```

more samples on [MSDN](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-order-by/), hope it helps :)

Comment: I don't get you.. There is only one table t1

Comment: then you can just use one, _delete_ the other parameters ` t1.current IN (t1.history)` and delete this line `WHEN 't2.history' THEN 2` I was trying to give you something simple you can append to your query and expand if needed..

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly you want l´the lowest number in history that is lower than the history number to the current number 5

ia hd to replace current with curr_id, dbfiddle doesn't like it as column name

> ```
> CREATE TABLE T1 (
>   curr_id INT NOT NULL,
>   [History] INT
> );
>
> INSERT INTO T1
>   (curr_id, History)
> VALUES
>   ('5', '6'),
>   ('6', '4'),
>   ('2', '3');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT TOP 1
>     curr_id AS 'current',
>     history
> FROM
>     T1
> WHERE
>     HISTORY <= (SELECT 
>             History
>         FROM
>             T1
>         WHERE
>             curr_id = 5)
> ORDER BY history ASC
> ;
>
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> current | history
> ------: | ------:
>       2 |       3
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     curr_id AS 'current',
>     history
> FROM
>     T1
> WHERE
>     HISTORY <= (SELECT 
>             History
>         FROM
>             T1
>         WHERE
>             curr_id = 5)
> ORDER BY history ASC;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> current | history
> ------: | ------:
>       2 |       3
>       6 |       4
>       5 |       6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c7c533c0b86437937f5291f0f86c4e7)*